# git new branch is not pulling any file

Tags: git

I am trying to create a local copy of fedora28 kernel, according to Fedora official docs the procedure is:

create a local copy of  master kernel branch:

```
$ fedpkg clone -a kernel
```

this works, it creates a kernel directory with lots of files. because the f28  kernel is a separate branch (master is for rawhie), is had to run

```
$ git checkout origin/f28
```

this is not working there is not any origin/f28 or any f28 directory, just the same kernel directory(which is master branch).
in the same, docs it says you have to start editing some files, but i don't hava any beacause the f28 directory is not copyied, running `git branch -a` I see `origin/f28` as my head branch after I `run checkout` command.
should I have to run another command to copy the files?
if I run `git pull` I got a lot of errors like this:

error: It is not possible to pull because you have un-merged files

How could it be posible if it is a new branch, never used, I even don't have any file to modify yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment it could be when you first pulled the files it changed read, write and execute permissions or it might have changed the timestamp of the files.

What so ever; If it says "you have un-merged files" just run `git status` and you should see what files have changed. You say you didn't change anything so just drop all those changes. Be aware before continuing that you will lose all changes with the next command. So if you want to remove all changes run:

```
git reset --hard # removes staged and working directory changes
```

now it should work.